Tensorflow 2.0.0 and 2.4.0: differences between Model.fit() and model.fit_generator()?
I'm new to tensorflow and try to run codes in tensorflow 2.4.0. The codes are listed below
train_generator = DataGenerator(trainfile, database_path=database_path, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_generator= DataGenerator(valfile, database_path=database_path, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
model.compile(loss=loss, optimization=Adam)
result=model.fit(generator=train_generator,
                                 validation_data=val_generator,
                                 epochs=epochs,
                                 workers=workers,
                                 use_multiprocessing=False,
                                 callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='./log'), checkpoint, rlr],
                                 initial_epoch=0
                                 )

The DataGenerator is a class of generator pre-defined.
class DataGenerator (keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, filename, database_path, X1dim=(298, 257, 2), X2dim=(75, 1, 1792, 2), ydim=(298, 257, 2, 2), batch_size=4, shuffle=True):
        self.filename = filename
        self.X1dim = X1dim
        self.X2dim = X2dim
        self.ydim = ydim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()
        self.database_path = database_path

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int(np.floor(len(self.filename) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        # Generate indexes of the batch
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

        # Find list
        filename_temp = [self.filename[k] for k in indexes]

        # Generate data
        [X1, X2], y = self.__data_generation(filename_temp)

        return [X1, X2], y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.filename))
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __data_generation(self, filename_temp):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples'
        # Initialization
        X1 = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.X1dim))
        X2 = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.X2dim))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.ydim))

        # Generate data
        for i, ID in enumerate(filename_temp):
            info = ID.strip().split(' ')
            X1[i, ] = np.load(self.database_path+'AV_model_database/mix/' + info[0])
            for j in range(2):
                y[i, :, :, :, j] = np.load(self.database_path+'AV_model_database/crm/' + info[j + 1])
                X2[i, :, :, :, j] = np.load(self.database_path+'../model/face_embedding/face1022_emb/' + info[j + 3])
        return [X1, X2], y

The error returns
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Looking-to-Listen-at-the-Cocktail-Party-master\train.py", line 138, in <module>
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\cocktail\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1064, in fit
    steps_per_execution=self._steps_per_execution)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\cocktail\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1099, in __init__
    adapter_cls = select_data_adapter(x, y)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\cocktail\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 964, in select_data_adapter
    _type_name(x), _type_name(y)))
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input <class 'data_load.DataGenerator>, <class 'NoneType>'

But if I just change model.fit() to model.fit_generator() and then run these codes in tensorflow 2.0.3. These codes can be run successfully. Also, I tried to use model.fit_generator() in 2.4.0 and the error is the same. Do anyone know why this happens and how to fix this?
Actually I want to use tensorflow 2.4.0 since 2.4.0 supports my gpu and cuda. But this error is annoying.
I changed my cuda version to 10.0 and made cudnn compatible but tensorflow 2.0.0 still can't use gpu so I have to struggle to fix the problem in tensorflow 2.4.0 such that I can run algorithm in gpu. Can anyone help?

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

I don't understand. Did you try to use fit_generator() in 2.4.0? Did you get error when you use fit_generator() in  2.4.0?

I added the full traceback in question body, thank you for advice. I also tried fit_generator in 2.4.0 but the error is same as using fit().

I would try two things: (1) as for me problem can makes Generator so for test I would try to use some other Generator - maybe documentation show some example. (2) I would try to find Failed to find data adapter that can handle input <class 'data_load.DataGenerator>, <class 'NoneType>' in Google. Maybe someone already had this problem.

ie. python - Tensorflow Data Adapter Error: ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input - Stack Overflow
